# what is the use of Abstract modifier with primitive data type in java?

Tags: java

What is use of `abstract` modifier with primitive data type? In `java.io.Reader class,read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` return type is "abstract int".
Can we use only "int" instead of "abstract int" or not?
What is the diffrence between these two?

Comment: The method is abstract. You may want to read a tutorial about abstract classes.

Comment: It doesn't return "abstract int" (no such a thing), the method that returns an `int`, is an *abstract* method.

Answer (score 1):

You mis-interpreted the signature of the method, it doesn't mean the `int` returned is `abstract`. It simply means that the method is abstract which means :

- Classes that extends class containing this method will be abstract if they don't override the method.
- You can't call the method directly.